# Sitecore: We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

It is throwing the following `exception` after submitting the data using `Web form` created after it is upgraded from Web Form for `Marketers` `2.1.0` to `2.3.0.` Followed the step by step upgrade instructions.

```
Exception in the Log file: 
6772 22:24:13 WARN  Web Forms for Marketers: an exception:  has occured while trying to execute an action.
Error/Warning on the UI:
Sitecore: We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request.  Your data may not have been correctly saved
```

However, it is saving the data to database, and when I view the report for the same form using Web Form Reports, nothing is shown.

Action Method : Save to Database

Comment: What sort of Save Actions do you have on the form? Anything custom?

Comment: Save to Database is the action

Comment: Normally the actual error is shown in the log file after the message you have shown. Could you give us a little more info on the log entries?

Comment: One More info : I have upgraded web forms for marketers from 2.1.0 to 2.3.0 following sdn documentation.

Comment: Heartbeat 15:02:53 WARN  Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
3792 15:02:54 WARN  Web Forms for Marketers: an exception:  has occured while trying to execute an action.
Heartbeat 15:02:59 WARN  Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.

Comment: If there are ANY other save actions on the form, I'd suggest removing them one by one and seeing which is causing the issue since your form is saving to the database... That same error message will appear for any save action issue unless you specify otherwise so its most likely just another save action with configuration issues..

Answer (score 0):

The reading/creating counters warning is covered by adding the 'Performance log users' role to the account used by the application pool [as previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445827/sitecore-has-no-necessary-permissions-for-reading-creating-counters). It seems unlikely that this is causing the WFFM error, but it's worthing getting rid of the warning, restart IIS, and try again.

Comment: I am getting only this error when I execute the submit/Save To Database action: WARN  Web Forms for Marketers: an exception:  has occured while trying to execute an action.

Comment: This is Resolved! Please refer to the below link  http://daveleigh.co.uk/web-forms-for-marketers-an-exception-has-occured-while-trying-to-execute-an-action/

Answer (score 0):

This is related to smtp setup on Send Email Message action which is used on webforms for marketers.
Refer:
http://blog.arkesystems.com/post/2010/05/18/SiteCoreWeb-Forms-for-Marketers-Send-Email.aspx