# Sitecore 7.2 Multiserver Environment Web Form for Marketers database error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

We have sitecore 7.2 and Web Form for Marketers 2.4 Rev. 151103 installed on a 3 server environment. One server is our content management (CM), one is our content delivery (CD) and the third one is our SQL server. I have the form successfully created and submitting on our CM server without an issue.

On the CD server we are getting the following error "**We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correclty saved."** I made sure we had the formsDataProvider configured on the Sitecore.Forms.config. Is there an additioanl setting for the CD server that I am missing for this to work?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have errors in the log files?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in the logs that is help. It just says Error Application Error

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured WFFM on the CD to use the web service on the CM server? Hardened CD instances don't have the database connectivity that the CM has ('master' is missing) so I have seen this error happen there. The save action needs to be able to execute inside the authoring environment, so you need to setup the remoteWfmService.

The documentation is available in PDF form here:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,4/Documentation.aspx

> ### 2.11.1 Deploying the Module on the Content Delivery Server
>
> 3. Add the following connection string to the connectionstrings.config file in all content delivery servers:
>
>    `<add name="remoteWfmService" connectionString="url=http://[masterserver]/sitecore%20modules/shell/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Staging/WfmService.asmx;user=[domain\username];password=[password];timeout=60000" />`
>
> Where
>
> - [masterserver] – IP or the host name of the master server.
> - [domain\username] – Sitecore user (full name). The necessary access rights depend on the items that the form is using.
> - [password] – user’s password

It may also be related to email actions as described here: [Sitecore: We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177559/sitecore-we-experienced-a-technical-difficulty-while-processing-your-request-y)

Comment: Jay thank you for your answer. Yes we did make sure to add the remoteWfmService on the connection string. My first thought was the email as well so I have the Save to Database as the only action and it was still failing.